# Installing C++ libraries in codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, libraries, yaml-cpp

I need to run some code which involves yaml-cpp and cvode libraries in code blocks. I have tried to install the libraries and link to the compiler (I think that,s what I did) but it doesn't seem to work. I have also tried including the library in the directory and opening using:

```
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"
```

But I keep getting errors that there is no such file in directory. I am also having to change the directory in all the h files and I feel like this is not what I should be doing. However if I leave it as

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
```

I get the same error.

Can someone please walk me through exactly how I can get the library to work?

I have tried building it with cmake which didn't show any error messages and I have the files built in their own folder on my computer.

I have no clue on how to fix this issue.

Thank you

Edit:

(I am on windows using a gcc compiler)

So the problem is that the library can't be found.

Does the library need to be in the same directory or can I link it in its own folder?

Once that is done should I include the library in angle brackets <> or quotation marks ""?

Comment: It means it's not able to find the path where the library got installed.

Comment: This question is really dependent on how you compile and link, how your folder structure looks like and how you installed this specific library

Comment: `Code::Blocks` is an IDE that runs on multiple different operating systems and can use several different compilers. If you are using MS windows the answer may be different than linux or macOS. Although in any case the answer depends on how you installed the specific library, where you installed it and what options you used to tell the compiler and linker where to look.

Comment: Show, don't tell. "I have tried to install the libraries" How? What OS? "I keep getting errors" Where? What compiler are you using? What is the compilation command? Code blocks is utterly irrelevant. It is a glorified text editor (and not *too* glorified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: you need to compile the yaml-cpp library.
After compilation, using cmake, (in the yaml-cpp/build folder) you will find the files:
`libyaml-cpp.dll`  and  `libyaml-cpp.dll.a`. 
Step 2: Create a new project in CodeBlocks. 
Step 3: From Project menu go to Build options and set C++11 language version or higher. 
Step 4: Now you have to set the paths for the header files and for the linking of the library 
 
[image: Path to yaml-cpp include directory] 
 
[image: Path to yaml-cpp/build folder] 
 
[image: Add library file name] 
 
Step 5: copy file `libyaml-cpp.dll` to your project folder containing your *.cbp file (Codeblocks Project file). 
Step 6: copy the same dll to `bin\Debug` and `bin\Release` directories. 
Step 7: Now, in your sources, you can write `#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>`  because you told to CodeBlocks where to find the library files. 
That's all.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Can you please explain step 6 a bit more? The folders should be within the yaml files? I can go into bin but there are no folders debug and release. Should I have to make them?

Thanks again

Comment: a CodeBlocks project, normally creates the subdirectory bin and within this the subdirectories Debug and Realise. Inside these folders you will find the executable files of your project. The libyaml-cpp.dll (without .a extension) must be copied to yuor executable folder.

Answer (score -4):

if your file header location is same with your main program just

`#include "yourheader.h"`

Comment: That does not really help the author because there are bigger problems