# How to link Graphviz with Codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks, graphviz

I want to visualise a graph using Graphviz, and am coding on C++ in Code::Blocks, is there any way of linking Graphviz with Codeblocks? If yes, how should I do it?

Comment: What is your operating system and which version of CodeBlocks do you use? Which compiler do you use?

Comment: CodeBlocks does not connect to Graphviz, but the program you will write must link Graphviz as a static or dynamic library.

Comment: So, I'm using Code::Blocks 20.03, and GCC compiler. I have created the dot file, and am using system("cd PathToGraphvizBin && dot -Tpng inputfilename.dot -o outputfilename.png") however, it does not create the file. If I use ">" in place of "-o" it creates the file but the file cannot be opened as it is damaged. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that I do not know the Graphviz library, what you did should work from cmd windows (after setting the system enviroment paths). 
If you want to write a C++ program that uses the Graphviz library you need to learn how to statically link to a compiled library (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68637757/installing-c-libraries-in-codeblocks/68662788#68662788)) and then consult the documentation present on the Graphviz website ([libguide.pdf](https://graphviz.org/pdf/libguide.pdf)).